# Can advantages be left unspent?

Tags: combat, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

I find that my players end up with a lot of advantages, and sometimes we just don't have any use for them. Especially the last round of combat. Am I missing something here or is it ok to just ignore those single/couple left over advantages?

I was thinking about making up tiny rewards on the spot but then I need to start worrying about balance.

Do the rules allow for advantages to be unspent?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question as written is a little unclear. Are you asking what the rules say about this situation, or for advice - and if the latter, what goal are you trying to achieve? "Should I do X" isn't really a question we can answer; either "do the rules allow X" or "what's the best way to use X to accomplish goal Y?" is better.

Comment: Also, specifically which Star Wars game are you playing? Age of Rebellion? Please [edit] your tags to specify.

Comment: Thanks! I tried editing my question. And added the tag, too. Sorry, I figured the basic mechanics were the same for all variants?

Comment: For the variants they are the same, but "Star Wars" in itself is not a game/does not only encompass the fantasy flight star wars games ;)

Comment: Duh. Of course. Mea culpa :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unless there is a weapon/gear effect, or other trigger for advantage to activate extra advantage is just extra**

The most common use of advantage is to recover strain (1 to 1), but I'm assuming your players are already looking at the table on p.206 in the core book and using those options. If so then left over advantage really is just extra and not useable once you've spent as much as you can on the 6-2 table.

Similarly on some non-combat checks you can have extra net success and it does not really do anything for you.

Answer (score 6):

**Advantages are always advantageous**  and Threats are always threatening

Quoting from Age of Rebellion (p. 30) (Edge of the Empire is, I think, word-for -word the same):

> Having one or more net Advantage symbols indicates a positive side effect or benefit.
>
> Advantage and Threat can be used to fuel a *wide variety* of side effects.

And p.217/218

> Just as they can be spent in a non-combat skill check, (A) and (T) can be spent in a combat check to gain *incidental benefits*. ... *some* of the options are more clearly defined.
>
> However, there are other options for spending (A) and (T) as well. A list of the most common can be found on Table 6-2 ... **Keep in mind that these are not intended to be the only options available. As always, players and GMs may invent other ways to spend (A) and (T), depending on specific circumstances of the encounter. Any option that the players and GM agree upon can be viable.**

To illustrate with an example: imagine we are trying to infiltrate an Imperial detention block for some reason. We have come up with a cunning plan involving putting binders around the wrists of the wookie, donning stormtrooper armor and pretending to be conducting a prisoner transfer. However, we fail to deceive the guards and a firefight breaks out at the end of which, I am left with a handful of unused advantage. Thinking quickly, I spend 1 of these to find an open comlink to central control and the remainder to add blue dice to my dice pool when I try to convince them that everything is OK - perhaps I say:

> Uh, we had a slight weapons malfunction, but uh... everything's perfectly all right now. We're fine. We're all fine here now, thank you. How are you?

Trust me, I am going all the help I can get with this one.

For more (and better) brilliance about interpreting dice pools listen to [Skill Monkey](http://www.madadventurers.com/category/field-recordings/skill-monkey/) from the Mad Adventurer's Society.